# On properties of symmetric i.i.d ramdom walks

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, reflection

I am currently trying to prove the reflection principle, using step by step instrucions. Let $X_i,\forall i\in\mathbb{N}$ be i.i.d. distributed, real, symmetricly distributed random variables. Define $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $N=\inf  \{m\leq n:S_m>a\}$. In the first step I showed, that for all $Z$ with symmetric distribution, $P(Z\geq 0)\geq \frac{1}{2}$. In the second step I am supposed to decompose $\{S_n\geq a\}$ using values of $N$. However, I do not know, what it means to decompose using values of N, so I am stuck. Any help or explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: What does $\inf\{m \leq n : S_m>a\}$ mean?  Why should there be an integer $m$ that satisfies both $S_m>a$ and $m\leq n$?

Comment: I thought the set might be empty as well, would that pose a problem?